# Hibernate HQL casting java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I am new in Hibernate.

When i try to inverse boolean

`@Query(value = "update ToDo t set t.done= (abs(t.done -1))  where t.id=:id")
    public void toogleDone(@Param("id") long id);`

i have this exception:

> ```
> [2014-01-20 16:20:38] java.lang.ClassCastException:
> ```
>
> java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongTypeDescriptor.unwrap(LongTypeDescriptor.java:36) at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:57) ...

when i try this query:

`@Query(value = "update ToDo t set t.done= (NOT t.done)  where t.id=:id")

```
public void toogleDone(@Param("id") long id);`
```

i have exception:

> [2014-01-20 16:28:58] unexpected AST node: not [update org.teamdev.todo.model.domain.ToDo t set t.done= (NOT t.done)  where t.id=:id]

Do you anybody have any idea to inverse boolean in HQL?

Comment: Try: `set t.done = (t.done==false)`

Comment: I had tried it too, i had exception `unexpected token =` near false

Comment: How about one `=` alone? `set t.done = (t.done=false)`? Or `set t.done = (t.done < 1)` or `set t.done = ((t.done+0) < 1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `set t.done = (t.done=false)`, so the Query would be:

```
update ToDo t set t.done = (t.done=false) where t.id=:id
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want to toggle the bit value? You can accomplish this using CASE.

```
update ToDo t set t.done = (case when t.done = 1 then 0 else 1 end) where t.id=:id
```

Comment: Yes i tried. And i had in JPA console good result. But when it running in my program, it crashed with exception : 
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
 at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.setParameter(QueryImpl.java:451)
 ...`
I`m don`t know, what the matter, but neither one from variants except for `set t.done = (t.done=false)` not working.